# Showing the complete graph $K_{2m}$ is $K_{1,m}$ decomposable

Tags: graph-theory

> Show the complete graph $K_{2m}$ is $K_{1,m}$ decomposable.

I can see that it looks to be true and even have an algorithm that seems to work, but I can't prove that it's right. I think I understand the proof that K2m+1 is H decomposable for all graceful graphs  H of order m, but that proof strategy seems to fail here. I can't see how the fact that K 1,m is graceful for all m helps me here. I've been working all the problems from The Fascinating World of Graph Theory by Benjamin, Chartrand, & Zhang. This is the 8th problem from the excercises for chapter 8. I'm probably missing something since non of the problems have been overly difficult to this point.

I can see there will be 2m-1 copies of K1,m in K2m and have been playing with K6 and K1,3 just to explore ideas. I can see that if I take 5 copies of K1,3 and place them in a circle I can use 1 edge from each and connect it to a 6th vertex to  complete 1 vertex of K6. Now I have 10 edges left from the 5 copies of K1,3 to play with. Easy to complete K6 from here, but how do I prove it! Show does mean prove right? Thanks for any help or suggestions. Brett

Comment: I think one proof strategy might be to somehow show when you remove a vertex from K2m+1 an integral number of K1,m must remain. Hm...

Answer (score 1):

As you said, there will be $2m-1$ copies of $K_{1,m}$, and each will connect to the last vertex. Now we are left with $2m-1$ copies of $K_{1,m-1}$ to create $K_{2m-1}$.

However, observe that you can assign vertex $k$ edges $$(k,k+1 \bmod 2m-1), (k,k+2 \bmod 2m-1), \ldots, (k,k+m-1 \bmod 2m-1)$$
assuming vertices are numbered $0,1,\ldots,2m-2$. Note, that some edge not being covered would mean some other edge was doubled. Thus, it is enough to show that no edge will be used twice. This is true, because $(m-1)+(m-1) < 2m-1$, that is, if we interpreted each edge as a jump forward on a cycle of length $2m-1$, then a double edge would imply we could make the full circle in just two jumps, which is impossible.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thank you very much dtldarek for the correct  answer. I believe I follow your argument. You are assigning the correct number of edges (m-1)(2m-1) and it's not possible to duplicate an edge because of the reason you give. From your first paragraph, the problem is reduced to one that we know is possible by the more general theorem where a graceful graph of size M can be cyclically decomposed into the complete graph K2m+1 since K1,m-1 is graceful and K2(m-1)+1 = K2m-1.